# Makefile recompiling unchanged files

Tags: makefile, build-automation

I'm attempting to get my Makefile(s) to only recompile when files have changed and it works brilliantly for the Java target, but not for JS. There aren't any errors reported, but when I run `make bundle` the second time around, it still re-runs all of those commands.

The output of running `find ...` manually seems to produce exactly what is expected, with no extra or missing lines.

```
JAVA_SRC_DIR := .
JAVA_SOURCES := $(shell find $(JAVA_SRC_DIR) -name '*.java' -o -name '*pom.xml')

JS_SRC_DIR := ./ui-bundle
JS_EXCLUDE := \(node_modules\|coverage\)
JS_SOURCES := $(shell find $(JS_SRC_DIR) -name '*.js' -o -name '*.jsx' -o -name '.babelrc' -o -name 'package.json' | grep -v $(JS_EXCLUDE) | grep -v -e '^$')

bundle: $(JS_SOURCES)
    npm install
    ./node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js --verbose
    ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js package

service: $(JAVA_SOURCES)
    mvn clean install -pl "!integration"
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with it, but when I try to find what files `make` thinks has changed with `make -d | grep "\(older\|newer\)"` it doesn't find anything, but `make -d` concludes with:

```
 Finished prerequisites of target file `bundle'.
 Must remake target `bundle'.
```

Additionally `make -d` seems to try to run some sort of npm command.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with npm. Is `bundle` an actual file,or just a name for the rule?

Comment: @Beta bundle is just a name for the rule. It refers to 'bundling' JS modules into a single file so that the browser only has to load one.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Writing an Answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `bundle` is just a name for the rule, and the rule doesn't actually build a file named "bundle". No matter how new or old the prerequisites are, when you `make bundle`, Make sees that no such file exists, deduces that it must be built, and executes the rule.

If you want Make to refrain from executing the rule when the prerequisites have not changed, you must give it something to compare them to. If you can identify some file that the rule always modifies, you can make that file the target. I can't suggest a candidate because I don't know what `npm`, `jest` and `gulp` do, but suppose it's `jest_output`:

```
jest_output: $(JS_SOURCES)
    ...
```

Or you could have an actual file called `bundle`, which serves as a marker for Make, an empty file that has a name and modification time and nothing else:

```
bundle: $(JS_SOURCES)
    npm install
    ./node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js --verbose
    ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js package
    touch bundle
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense - I happen to have a folder name that matches the Java target, and I guess maven updates its timestamp. I ended up changing the name of the rule to match the existing folder name and it worked as expected. Just as a note for anyone else looking for this answer, apparently `make` is rather particular about where it's EOF is, and the final grep listed in the JS sources messes with that.